# Illegal instruction (core dumped) in cv::findHomography

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, amd-processor

I am getting this error:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

When calling:

```
cv::findHomography(query_points, reference_points, cv::RANSAC, homography_ransac_threshold_, h_mask);
```

This happen only an AWS EC2 g5 machine which has an AMD EPYC 7R32 CPU. The code works fine on other machines with Intel CPU.

I have built OpenCV (tired 4.8.1 and 4.51) from sources on the machine using:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF -D WITH_CUDNN=ON -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=8.6 -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX=8.6 -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/other_sources/opencv_contrib-4.5.1/modules -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_sfm=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DCPU_DISPATCH=SSE4_2,AVX -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-11.4 -DWITH_IPP=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_alphamat=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_aruco=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_bgsegm=OFF  -D BUILD_opencv_bioinspired=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_datasets=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_dpm=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_face=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_fuzzy=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_hdf=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_hfs=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_img_hash=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_java_bindings_generator=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_js=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_js_bindings_generator=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_line_descriptor=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_mcc=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_plot=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python_tests=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_quality=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_rapid=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_reg=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_rgbd=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_saliency=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_shape=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_structured_light=OFF  ..
```

The CMake out is:

```
-- Detected processor: x86_64
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3")
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: WEBP_LIBRARY
Cleaning INTERNAL cached variable: WEBP_INCLUDE_DIR
-- Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1). OpenJPEG will be built from sources
-- OpenJPEG: VERSION = 2.3.1, BUILD = opencv-4.5.1-openjp2-2.3.1
-- OpenJPEG libraries will be built from sources: libopenjp2 (version "2.3.1")
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11")
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gtkglext-1.0'
--   No package 'gtkglext-1.0' found
-- Found TBB (env): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so
-- CUDA detected: 11.4
-- CUDA: Using CUDA_ARCH_BIN=8.6
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86;-D_FORCE_INLINES;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=compute_86
-- LAPACK(OpenBLAS): LAPACK_LIBRARIES: /usr/local/lib/libopenblas.so
-- LAPACK(OpenBLAS): Support is enabled.
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/humamhelfawi/other_sources/opencv-4.5.1/_build/python_loader
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   YES
-- freetype2:   YES (ver 21.0.15)
-- harfbuzz:    YES (ver 1.7.2)
-- Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings.
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- Found AMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found AMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libamd.so
-- Found CAMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found CAMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamd.so
-- Found CCOLAMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found CCOLAMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccolamd.so
-- Found CHOLMOD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found CHOLMOD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcholmod.so
-- Found COLAMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found COLAMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcolamd.so
-- Found SPQR headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found SPQR library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspqr.so
-- Found Config headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found Config library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsuitesparseconfig.so
-- Did not find Intel TBB library, assuming SuiteSparseQR was not compiled with TBB.
-- Adding librt to SuiteSparse_config libraries (required on Linux & Unix [not OSX] if SuiteSparse is compiled with timing).
-- Could NOT find METIS (missing: METIS_INCLUDE_DIR METIS_LIBRARY)
-- Found AMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found AMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libamd.so
-- Found CAMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found CAMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamd.so
-- Found CCOLAMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found CCOLAMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccolamd.so
-- Found CHOLMOD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found CHOLMOD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcholmod.so
-- Found COLAMD headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found COLAMD library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcolamd.so
-- Found SPQR headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found SPQR library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspqr.so
-- Found Config headers in: /usr/include/suitesparse
-- Found Config library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsuitesparseconfig.so
-- Did not find Intel TBB library, assuming SuiteSparseQR was not compiled with TBB.
-- Adding librt to SuiteSparse_config libraries (required on Linux & Unix [not OSX] if SuiteSparse is compiled with timing).
-- Could NOT find METIS (missing: METIS_INCLUDE_DIR METIS_LIBRARY)
-- Checking for module 'tesseract'
--   No package 'tesseract' found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Module opencv_tracking disabled because opencv_plot dependency can't be resolved!
-- Module opencv_stereo disabled because opencv_tracking dependency can't be resolved!
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.fp16.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin256.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin256.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin512.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.avx2.cpp
-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/humamhelfawi/other_sources/opencv-4.5.1/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/features2d/src/fast.avx2.cpp
--
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/humamhelfawi/other_sources/opencv_contrib-4.5.1/modules
--     Version control (extra):     unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2023-10-27T19:43:28Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.4.0-1099-aws x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.26.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_2 AVX
--       SSE4_2 (6 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          m pthread cudart_static dl rt nppc nppial nppicc nppidei nppif nppig nppim nppist nppisu nppitc npps cublas cudnn cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib
--     3rdparty dependencies:
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres features2d flann freetype gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo stitching superres surface_matching text ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired cudacodec datasets dpm face fuzzy hdf hfs img_hash java_bindings_generator js_bindings_generator line_descriptor mcc plot python_tests quality rapid reg rgbd saliency sfm shape structured_light world
--     Disabled by dependency:      stereo tracking
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cvv java julia matlab ovis python2 python3 viz
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         YES
--
--   GUI:
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_2)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
--       avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
--
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2017.0 interface 9107)
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      YES (/usr/local/lib/libopenblas.so)
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.4)
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
--
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.4, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             86
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            86
--
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.4.0)
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/humamhelfawi/other_sources/opencv-4.5.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
--
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done (3.4s)
-- Generating done (0.8s)
```

it seems one of the optimizations instruction is called which the CPU does not support.

May you please help me altering the CMake call to disable that optimization?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Look at the open issue on [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19020) they also provide some instructions to check and suspect opencv fail on some AMD cpus

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, it turn out that **OpenBLAS** causes the problem. I have excluded it from OpenCV building and the error went away.